# An unhandled win32 exception occured calling dispose on AudioGraph

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

I've written a method to get a float array representing the samples of a music file. I'm using the class AudioGraph for this.

But when I dispose the AudioGraph, I get following error:
[image]
[image: VS error]

The error don't occure when Dispose is called but after the Method returned (after the next time I hit await).

The Code does not run on the UI Thread. Running on the UI Thread won't throw this error.

Not disposing the graph is another way to not throw this Error. I dislike both.

This is the Method:

```
    private static async Task<float[]> GetAudioBuffer(IStorageFile file, IProgress<double> progress)
    {
        float[] buffer;
        int currentPart = 0;
        progress.Report(currentPart, 0);
        var createAudioGraphResult = await Windows.Media.Audio.AudioGraph.CreateAsync(new Windows.Media.Audio.AudioGraphSettings(Windows.Media.Render.AudioRenderCategory.Media));
        if (createAudioGraphResult.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
            CallError();
        using (var graph = createAudioGraphResult.Graph)
        {


            var result = await graph.CreateFileInputNodeAsync(file);
            if (result.Status != AudioFileNodeCreationStatus.Success)
                CallError();
            var input = result.FileInputNode;
            {


                var output = graph.CreateFrameOutputNode();
                {

                    input.AddOutgoingConnection(output);
                    TaskCompletionSource<bool> waiter = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                    input.FileCompleted += (node, args) =>
                    {

                        if (!waiter.TrySetResult(true))
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This should be called only once");
                    };

                    graph.Start();

                    Task t = waiter.Task;
                    Task erg = null;
                    while (erg != t)
                    {
                        var delay = Task.Delay(500);
                        erg = await Task.WhenAny(t, delay);
                        var percentage = input.Position.TotalSeconds / input.Duration.TotalSeconds;
                        progress.Report(currentPart, percentage);
                    }

                    await waiter.Task;
                    progress.Report(currentPart, 1);
                    currentPart++;
                    graph.Stop();
                    using (var frame = output.GetFrame())
                    using (var lockedBuffer = frame.LockBuffer(Windows.Media.AudioBufferAccessMode.Read))
                    using (var refference = lockedBuffer.CreateReference())
                        unsafe
                        {
                            var memoryByteAccess = refference as IMemoryBufferByteAccess;
                            byte* p;
                            uint capacity;
                            memoryByteAccess.GetBuffer(out p, out capacity);

                            int length = (int)(capacity / sizeof(float));
                            float* b = (float*)p;
                            var channelCount = output.EncodingProperties.ChannelCount;
                            buffer = new float[length / channelCount];

                            for (int i = 0; i < length / channelCount; i++)
                            {
                                for (int j = 0; j < channelCount; j++)
                                    buffer[i] += b[i * channelCount + j];
                                buffer[i] /= channelCount;

                                var percentage = i / (double)(length / channelCount);
                                progress.Report(currentPart, percentage);
                            }
                            currentPart++;

                        }

                }
            }
        }

        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: The function definition is Task<float[]> and you are returning float[] buffer;

Comment: Just configure the debugger so it can show you the exception.  Project + Properties, Debug tab, select mixed.  It is liable to show you something you don't want to know about :)

Comment: @Hans Thanks for the help. Your right there are things someone should not see (~_~;)